# Select subset of records within the same table

Tags: sql

There is a table that presents a mapping for permissions and some objects, i.e. an object 'obj1' has 'perm1' and 'perm2' permissions, 'obj2' - 'perm1' and 'perm3'.

```
Permission_id Object_Id
  perm1      |   obj1
  perm2      |   obj1
  perm1      |   obj2
  perm3      |   obj2
```

The question is: how to get a subset of permissions which are applied to ALL objects? I.e. :

```
Permission_id 
    perm1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses counts and aggregations for this purpose:

```
select permission_id
from permissionobjects po
group by permission_id
having count(distinct object_id) = (select count(distinct object_id) from permissionobjects);
```